# Rule engine on a per customer basis

Tags: thingsboard

I am new to thingsboard. I have installed thingsboard CE(3.4.2) in my own server. I want to implement a rule node on a per customer basis. Because in my use case, a rule may apply to only one customer. For example, I may want to publish to external mqtt broker only for one customer or may be publish to some kafka node, again only for one customer. What is the easiest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

All customers of one tenant share the same rulechains.
I see 2 options to solve your problem:

- Having a seperate tenant for each customer --> would need more maintenance work
- Add filter nodes in the rulechain to check if data is incoming for the specific customer --> if yes, then forwared the data to MQTT or Kafka Broker

Sample rulenode for the second option:
[image]